# validate my form in Spring mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring

I have 4 text fields.If I have entered any data in these text fields,these values stored in my database using ajaxcall. I want to know how to validate these fields.My code is not works

```
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
     function validateform(){  
     var name=document.regform.emailid.value;  
     var password=document.regform.passWord.value;  
     if (name==null || name==""){  
     alert("Name can't be blank");  
     return false;  
      }
     else if(password.length<6){  
     alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");  
     return false;  
     }  
     } 




<form class="text-center" style="width:90%;padding-left:25px" name="regform"    onsubmit="return validateform()" >
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName"  placeholder="firstName" name="firstName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="lastName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailid" placeholder="emailid" name="emailid" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="passWord" placeholder="passWord" name="passWord">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobileNo" placeholder="mobileNo">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success   btn-block"  id="submitID">SUBMIT</button>
```

please correct my code?

Comment: Spring MVC??? you can validate it in JS itself na.. Please post your form submitting code also

Comment: even-though you are returning false the form will be submitted... you need to pass the event e as parameter of the validation Function and call e.preventDefault() this will block form submitting but if the validation is correct then you need to call ajax post to submit your form.. You will get lots of examples

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('url',{'send_post_var':'some_data'},function(result){});
```